# Angular 6: window.location condition not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I wrote code to load a different template when the screen size is small. It was working fine in Angular 4. Now after upgrade to Angular 6, it is throwing error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/student/student.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ' ""+((window.innerWidth) > 745 ?
      "student.component.html" :
      "student.component.mobile.html")' in 'C:\BIT_BUCKET\STUDENT\STUDENT-WEB\src\app\student'
```

Code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-lineside-inspection',
  templateUrl: "./"+((window.innerWidth) > 745 ?
      "student.component.html" :
      "student.component.mobile.html"),
  styleUrls: ['./student.component.css']
})
```

Version:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 9.8.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cdk                      6.3.2
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@angular/material                 6.3.2
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.1
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Comment: Write your code in your question if it's possible.

Comment: @MohammadDaliri - I have explained and put all code and given so much details, still I got Downvote. Now I am not able to ask any question. Please Upvote or let me know how I can improve to get upvote...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do something like this. But I would rather suggest  to have both the html content in one single file and use *ngIf directive. That's it.

Or If you really want to use two html pages, then you can use the selector.
Something like,
`<second-html-component *ngIf = "condition"></second-html-component>`

Comment: That a good idea which was my first thought when I first wrote the code, but deviated because there will be a lot of code in on html. So I wanted to have completely different html for mobile devices. Thank though!

Comment: If not that then you can use the selector right? Use *ngIf on the selector. `<second-html-component *ngIf ="condition"></second-html-component>`

Comment: That is what I did when I was not able to get it working with window.location condition. But I am still looking for putting a condition in templateUrl. Thanks though for looking my question